# Jquery not finding all Table Row Td cells?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having a really strange issue with Jquery. I have a table with many rows and td cells inside those rows. I try to access the td cell values and it just allows me to get the 1st child and that is it. This was working just fine a few days ago. All I did was upgrade to .net 4.5 and MVC4. I didn't even make a whole new MVC4 project, I just changed a couple guids in the MVC3 project and sln files according to an article by MS on how to upgrade from MVC3 to 4. This just doesn't make any sense why it can't find the children. Jquery is loaded!! See images below for what I am talking about. Anybody have any idea what is going on!?? Below is my function that is blowing up because it can't get all the childNodes.

[image: function code]
[image: watch pane]
[image: browser]
[image: loaded scripts]

Comment: without showing us a bit of code it'll be impossible you help. Ideally provide a link to a live example of the problem.

Comment: See image links. I can't give you all the code, its for my work.

Comment: Then it is really your work, not us.

Comment: If the code is so important you can't share it, you cannot expect an answer. Hire a(nother) professional.

Comment: If you want us to help you, give us something to work with.

Maybe you can give us a reduced subset of your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ als least.

Comment: I am sorry. But I found the answer to my own question. I needed to use the 'cells' property of the tr element instead of childNodes accessor. Not sure why it just stopped working all of a sudden when it used to but whatever. It is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry. But I found the answer to my own question. I needed to use the 'cells' property of the tr element instead of childNodes accessor. Not sure why it just stopped working all of a sudden when it used to but whatever. It is fixed.